# Stop email notification of cPanel backups in custom script

Tags: php, cpanel

I've been using the following (partial) code to backup my websites:

```
 Generated by https://www.ericzhang.me/projects/cpanel-auto-backup/
*/

$auth = base64_encode("{$cpuser}:{$cppass}");
$domain = "{$domain}";
$theme = "paper_lantern";
$ftp = false;
$ftp_server = "";
$ftp_username = "";
$ftp_password = "";
$ftp_port = "21";
$ftp_directory = "/";


$url = $domain . "/frontend/" . $theme . "/backup/dofullbackup.html";
$data = array();
$data['email'] = '';

if ($ftp) {
  $data["dest"] = "ftp";
  $data["server"] = $ftp_server;
  $data["user"] = $ftp_username;
  $data["pass"] = $ftp_password;
  $data["port"] = $ftp_port;
  $data["rdir"] = $ftp_directory;
}

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAuthorization: Basic $auth\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
  ),
  'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if ($result === FALSE) {
  exit("Error backing up server.");
}
```

Up until about 2 days ago, I wasn't receiving any email notifications (what I want).  But now I receive one after any backup.  My guess is that cPanel has changed its parameters so that without having some variable which says "no_email=1", that an email is sent.  I've tried adding `$data['email']=""` as well as `$data['email']=some_dumb_email_i_never_check@mysite.com` but I'm still getting the notifications.  Any chance anyone know of an additional variable which I can add to prevent the notifications?

Comment: What does this email state? Is your script capable of sending emails? You state this is a "cPanel backup", yet you've included a PHP snippet? So this is your own script? Which I guess you are running as a Cron Job? In which case CRON/cPanel might be configured to send an email on success (and/or failure - which is desirable). If the later then no amount of changing your script will change anything. But also, if your script hasn't changed then I would have thought that editing your script is unlikely to make a difference?

Comment: The email has the subject: A full backup of the account “my_account” with the primary domain “my_domain.com” has completed.  It then goes on to say "A full backup has completed and is available for download."  In addition, it says "This notice is the result of a request made by a computer with the IP address of “my ip” through the “fullbackup” service on the server with an attachment containing a trace of the backup process.  And, it is a cPanel backup, but one generated from my script (sorry for the lack of clarity).  I definitely haven't configured CRON or cPanel to send an email.

Comment: My thought is that a new parameter now needs to be added (again I haven't changed this script in years) due to some update with cPanel where I need to specifically say that I don't want to receive an email upon success.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. From other scripts I've seen, `$data['email'] = '';` would probably be sufficient, depending on where you are setting this and how the script is actually being called. Maybe include the _entire_ script in your question, rather than just a snippet (which doesn't really show much).

Comment: I would have thought that would work as well, but I fear it didn't; I've updated my post to include more details of the script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same issue. It looks like the scripts we're using are based upon a deprecated function. The fact that the script is deprecated may be why adding $data["email"] = ""; doesn't work any more.

See https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/cPanel+API+1+Functions+-+Fileman%3A%3Afullbackup for details

Apparently we need to rewrite our scripts using a new function:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/UAPI+Functions+-+Backup%3A%3Afullbackup_to_ftp

Comment: This seems like a reasonable explanation!  Are you using the LiveAPI PHP Class?  I think that this would be the easiest approach.  However, on shared hosting, I'm not convinced that I have access to the Class.